# How to change light intensity using a plugin

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo 7 recently had an update that allowed lights be added to robot models as children of links:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/2807/add-light-as-child-of-link/diff%3C/p%3E

The SDF spec supports things like light shape, distance, and attenuation, but the robot I'm working on has dimmable lights, and so far I haven't been able to find out how to change the light intensity using the gazebo API. I looked in gazebo:physics API and I was able to find the Light class as well as the LightState class, but those don't seem to govern the settings I'm looking for.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18419/how-to-change-light-intensity-using-a-plugin/) by [amish](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4508/amish/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should look into [rendering::Light](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1Light.html). There's an explanation [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17381/different-classes-for-light/) about the `Light`'s multiple personalities.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1